# Showing error for multiple empty inputs vuejs vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have three inputs as externalIP as External Host, externalHttpPort as Port and vendor as Vendor, I want to show error message if any of them is missing. but being specific about the name,

```
if (!this.externalIP || !this.externalHttpPort || !this.vendor) {
```

when I do if condition, this works but I am not sure how I can tell if which input is empty. only one way which left is to add 3 multiple `if`

something like this

```
  let error;
  error = !this.externalIP
    ? "External IP Address (or URL) is incorrect"
    : "" || !this.externalHttpPort
    ? "Port is missing" : "" || !this.vendor
    ? "Please choose camera vendor or add your camera snapshot URL." : ""
  if (!error == "") {
    this.setNotification({
      text: error,
      color: "warning",
      snackbar: true
    })
    return
  }
```

is there any other way of doing it? Also, Eslint show warning on indentations as well

Answer (score 1):

In this way, you can achieve the same result as by your logic without using multiple `if`. Also, this way will keep your `template` & logic clean/easily scalable.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    fields: [
      {
        key: 'externalIP',
        value: '',
        validationMessage: 'External IP Address (or URL) is incorrect'
      },
      {
        key: 'externalHttpPort',
        value: '',
        validationMessage: 'Port is missing'
      },
      {
        key: 'vendor',
        value: '',
        validationMessage: 'Please choose camera vendor or add your camera snapshot URL.'
      }
    ]
  },
  
  computed: {
    getError () {
      let e = ''
      for (let i in this.fields) {
        if (!this.fields[i].value) {
          e = this.fields[i].validationMessage
          break
        }
      }
      return e
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <input 
    v-for="(field, i) in fields"
    :key="i"
    v-model="fields[i].value"
  />
 
  <br>{{ getError }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may assign an error field variable within your error-checking condition.

Example for three variables and an `emptyField` variable denoting the empty variable name:

```
if ((!a && (emptyField = "a")) || 
    (!b && (emptyField = "b")) ||
    (!c && (emptyField = "c"))) {
    alert("Field " + emptyField + " is empty...");
}
```

Since JS lazily evaluates its arguments, `emptyField = "a"` will get executed only if `!a` is `true`.

Just note that lazy evaluation also causes the evaluation of conditions stop once a condition was hit, thus if `a` is null and also `b` is null, the alert would announce that "Field a is empty..."

Answer (score 0):

if vuetify you can use `rules` to check inputs

for example:
in your `template`:

```
<v-text-field
    rules="[rules.required]"
    />
```

and in your `data`:

```
data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        required: (value) => !!value || 'This field is required.'
      }
    }
  },
```

you can add any other checking to rules array and just add it to your input by passing it to rules prop

hope it helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VeeValidate to handle all of Validation job, maybe you will be interested in it: 
https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/